# Fix email subject on windows hosted Hg server notifications

Tags: windows, mercurial, hgrc

I followed the instructions here to get a Mercurial server hosted in IIS7:

http://www.firegarden.com/software/hosting-mercurial-repo-iis7-windows-server-2008r2-x64-python-isapi-cgi

It works great, clean urls and notifications get sent and are formatted to according to the template:

```
 [notify]
 sources = serve push pull bundle
 template = 
    details:   {baseurl}/rev/{node|short}
```

Ends up looking like this:

```
 -----Original Message-----
 From: mercurial@mydomain.net
 Sent: Thursday, January 17, 2013 10:42 PM
 To: Me
 Subject: D:/hg/Repositories/test: Again

 details:   http://hg.mydomain.net/test/rev/561563d3847e
```

But notice that the subject has the windows drive letter in it, rather than the url `http://hg.mydomain.net/test/`

Is there a way to fix it so that it shows the URL rather than the drive letter? Or maybe not the url, but just show the repository?

Answer (score 1):

The property called `strip` of the [Notify extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension) will help you do what you want. You can strip off the leading root for the repository in the subject line.

Comment: That seems to be the only option at this point.  Would like to have the URL instead of just stripping a certain number of roots.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define `Subject` section in your template config? Please refer to [this chapter](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id405715) for more information.

Comment: I followed that example and it does not work.  Adding the "Subject: ..." text just puts that text in the email body, but doesn't adjust the subject OF the email.